# how use image that stored in ftp server in my site?

Tags: php, upload, ftp

my website code host and file host such as image and zip files seperated from each other.
I use ftp-connect and login and ftp_put for upload image in my file host server via ftp which it's address is something like this dl.domain.com
and my site is domain.com and i want show images in my website pages, I don't know how to do this , is there any body can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the Problem?

If you host index.html on your domain example.com you can of course add external images to it.

```
<img src="http://subdomain.example.com/images/1.jpg" alt="1.jpg">
```

The only thing is that you need to use an absolute path like in my example.

Comment: are you sure? i used this but, it doesn't work.

Comment: i am! maybe your file-server doesnt allow hotlinking. then it is probably a problem. try a random image from another source and look what happens.

Comment: when you upload files you sholud write your address like this /public_html/images/ and for using and show them just write http://subdomain.example.com/images/image_name. and of course your subdoamin A record sholud be active